# HTML5 shiv breaking my code in IE9

Tags: javascript, html

I've just started testing my app in IE9 and now I get a blank page because of this code snippet:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script><![endif] -->
```

I use this HTML5 shim for support of HTML5 elements in IE6-IE8.

Basically, the page stops rendering as soon as it hits this code.

I know that IE9 supports conditional comments. I have other pages that use them and they render just fine.

I do set a compatability a few lines about this code like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

I don't know why it would break here, though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this order and try to use `IE=edge` instead of `IE=8`.

There is a space in your `<![endif] -->` tag, you should remove it and use like this `<![endif]-->`.

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    .....................................................
    .....................................................

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was there was the space you mentioned in my endif tag.

Comment: Thanks! Removing the space in the `<![endif] -->` worked for me too!